# manageObjectContext throwing unrecognized selector errors?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

My application is a typical non-document based core data application. I have modified none of the pre-provided project code and have been using the AppDelegate files that Xcode provides by default (the project's not large enough to warrant much more).

Now, when I try to add an item to one of my core data stores with

```
NSManagedObject *colorItemObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ColorItem" inManagedObjectContext: [NSApp managedObjectContext]];
    [colorItemObject setValue:[colorSetsArrayController valueForKeyPath:@"selection.colorSetName"] forKey:@"parent"];
```

it throws an unrecognized selector exception:

```
-[_NSStateMarker managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100118290
```

Similar errors occur from using [self managedObjectContext]. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure

```
 [NSApp managedObjectContext]
```

does not return a valid `managedObjectContext`. Have you made a category to `NSApplication` with a method called `managedObjectContext`? If not, change that to

```
[self managedObjectContext]
```

and it should work. (I assumed your code is inside your app delegate.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have also tried [[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext] and [self manageObjectContext]. They all compile fine without any warnings but will throw an error during runtime

Comment: [self managedObjectContext] does the same as above - that is, - [_NSStateMarker managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100118290. Same goes for [[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext].

Comment: Could you show the implementation of `-managedObjectContext`? Are you doing `retain/release` correctly? If you run `analyze` from the Xcode menu bar (it's below the `build` menu item) what does it say?

Comment: The implementation isn't even mine, it's just the standard code included in every Core Data project. This baffles me because it's worked fine in other projects.

Analyze shows nothing outside of the norm, with a couple bogus IB errors (talking about overlapping views).

Comment: That's indeed very strange. Did you recently make changes to the data model? How about completely cleaning the build directory and build the app again?

Comment: My data model is quite simple and I doubt it's the cause of the problem (though I suppose it could be). Cleaning and rebuilding does not change anything, unfortunately.